# Passing Navigation to a Function Component

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

This Is My Home Page Code:

```js
import React from "react";
//More Imports

export default class Home extends React.Component {
 //Some Code
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <ScrollView>
      //Some Code
          <View style={styles.barContainer}>
            <Button
              title="Add Lesson"
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ThisLesson")}
            />
          </View>
          //Some Code
          {ScrollViewWithCards}
      //Some Code
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//Some Style
});

const cards = [
  {
    day: "3",
    month: "Jan",
    numberOfPeople: "4",
    time: "17:00-18:00",
    title: "Dance Class",
    image: require("../../../assets/images/image1.jpeg"),
  },
  //More Cards...
];

const ScrollViewWithCards = (
  <ScrollView>
    {cards.map((card, index) => (
      <View key={index} style={styles.cardContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("ThisLesson", {
              image: card.image,
              day: card.day,
              month: card.month,
              time: card.time,
              title: card.title,
              numberOfPeople: card.numberOfPeople,
            })
          }
        >
          <HomeCard
            image={card.image}
            day={card.day}
            month={card.month}
            time={card.time}
            title={card.title}
            numberOfPeople={card.numberOfPeople}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    ))}
  </ScrollView>
);
```

I'm mapping through an array of static data and rendering cards unto the screen
I made the cards pressable so that they take me to another page,
when I click the card it **Returns an error:**`Reference Error: Can't find variable: navigation`
**But the Button Above the Cards Works Just Fine**

What Am I Doing Wrong?
I tried the `useNavigation` Hook but it didn't work either

**Update**
This is my HomeCard component:

```js
import React from "react";
//More Imports

const HomeCard = (props) => {
  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
//Some Code
    </View>
  );
};
export default HomeCard;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//Some Style
});

const smallAvatars = [
//Some Array
];
```

I passed `{navigation}` to  `ScrollViewWithCards` like so:

```js
const ScrollViewWithCards =({navigation})=>()
```

but now I'm Getting another Error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`

## Solution

The Solution for this Problem is to transform `ScrollViewWithCards` to a function component, then pass props to it and add return:

```js
const ScrollViewWithCards = (props) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {cards.map((card, index) => (
        <View key={index} style={styles.cardContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() =>
              props.navigation.navigate("ThisLesson", {
                image: card.image,
                day: card.day,
                month: card.month,
                time: card.time,
                title: card.title,
                numberOfPeople: card.numberOfPeople,
              })
            }
          >
            <HomeCard
              image={card.image}
              day={card.day}
              month={card.month}
              time={card.time}
              title={card.title}
              numberOfPeople={card.numberOfPeople}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

and then in the main render:
`<ScrollViewWithCards navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the const navigation inside the render function, and it wont be accessible inside other functions, so you have to use

this.props.navigation.navigate

Then you can simply do

```
const ScrollViewWithCards =()=> (
  <ScrollView>
    {cards.map((card, index) => (
      <View key={index} style={styles.cardContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate("ThisLesson", {
              image: card.image,
              day: card.day,
              month: card.month,
              time: card.time,
              title: card.title,
              numberOfPeople: card.numberOfPeople,
            })
          }
        >
          <HomeCard
            image={card.image}
            day={card.day}
            month={card.month}
            time={card.time}
            title={card.title}
            numberOfPeople={card.numberOfPeople}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    ))}
  </ScrollView>
);
```

Comment: But then I get another Error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')` my component is a Function, not a Class

Comment: you pass the props to ScrollViewWithCards right ? can you update the question with new code ?

Comment: I can't write this line `<ScrollViewWithCards navigation={this.props.navigation}/>`
I will get Element type is Invalid

Comment: try this.props.navigation.navigate("ThisLesson",{})

Comment: i thought its a separate component

Comment: Still No Luck, `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220192/discussion-between-niko-konovalov-and-guruparan-giritharan).

Comment: I can't make ScrollViewWithCards a function, It's just a placeholder for my code to make the main render better looking

Answer (score 0):

In the routing section, you need to mention the both component like this,

```
<Stack.Screen name="<your component name>" component={your component class} />
```

please don't forget to import the files at the above.
and then you can use the navigation props like,

```
this.props.navigation //for class component
props.navigation //for functional component
```

or if you have parent child relation in your compoent try this one:

```
<YOUR_COMPONENT navigation={props.navigation}/> // functional component
<YOUR_COMPONENT navigation={this.props.navigation}/> // class component
```

Comment: please provide example for FC to set options in it